# Cannot interpret state of this BitVector32

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, bitvector

I am debugging some code right now (VS 2019, .NET Framework 4.7.2), stopped at a breakpoint, using the **Immediate Window** to evaluate variables. I have a `BitVector32` which I am not understanding its state. Here is the content of the **IW**:

```
stillInHand.ToString()
"BitVector32{00000000000000000000000000001100}"
stillInHand
{BitVector32{00000000000000000000000000001100}}
    Data: 12
stillInHand[0]
true
stillInHand[1]
false
stillInHand[2]
false
stillInHand[3]
false
stillInHand[4]
true
stillInHand[5]
false
stillInHand[6]
false
stillInHand[7]
false
```

There have been no calls to any of the `Create*` methods, and `stillInHand` was created with the `BitVector32(Int32)` ctor. Shouldn't indices 2 & 3 be `true` and all the rest be `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Actually**, this issue is related to the understanding of the index of `BitVector32[ ]`.

**First of all**, `stillInHand[1]` doesn’t mean to get the second bit of stillInHand(BitVector32). It represents this action: use `00 00 … 00 01` to perform `&`(AND) operation with stillInHand(BitVector32).

**For an example**: `stillInHand(BitVector32)` is `00 00 00 00 00 … 00 00 00 11 00`, and `1` is `00 00 00 00 00 … 00 00 00 00 01`. Then perform `&`(AND) operation.

```
00 00 00 00 00 … 00 00 00 11 00        12      &(AND)

00 00 00 00 00 … 00 00 00 00 01       `1`

--------------------------------------------

00 00 00 00 00 … 00 00 00 00 00
```

And you can see that the last bit(focus on the index value `1`) changes from `1` to `0`, so the result will be `false`, if you output or see the result of `stillInHand[1]`.

**So**, for `stillInHand[2]`, you can see

```
00 00 00 00 00 … 00 00 00 11 00        12      &(AND)

00 00 00 00 00 … 00 00 00 00 10        2

--------------------------------------------

00 00 00 00 00 … 00 00 00 00 00
```

The second to last bit(focus on the index value `2`)  changes from `1` to `0`, so the result will be `false` too.

And for `stillInHand[8]`, you can see

```
00 00 00 00 00 … 00 00 00 11 00        12      &(AND)

00 00 00 00 00 … 00 00 00 10 00        8

--------------------------------------------

00 00 00 00 00 … 00 00 00 10 00
```

The fourth to last bit(focus on the index value `8`)  doesn’t change and it remains as `1`, so the result will be `true`.

**Actually**, if you analyze the source code from here: [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/specialized/bitvector32.cs), you can see these codes:

```
/// <devdoc>
///    <para>Gets or sets a value indicating whether all the specified bits are set.</para>
/// </devdoc>

public bool this[int bit] {
   get {
            return (data & bit) == (uint)bit; 
            //clear other bits (to 0) through the AND operation of the data and mask.
            //If the result of the operation is equal to the mask, return true.
            //Otherwisse, return false.
       }
   set {
            if (value) {
                data |= (uint)bit;
                //data = data OR mask, set the specified bit to “1”
            }
            else {
                data &= ~(uint)bit;
                //data = data AND ~mask, set the specified bit to “0”
            }
        }
}
```

**Of course**, you can consider `it` as `mask`, and this will be easy to understand.

Comment: Great explanation. The MSFT documentation on this is frankly a little obtuse - they could have done a better job, as this isn't immediately obvious. Good to know now!